# Distributively multiplying matrices of different shapes and then adding them up in numpy

Tags: numpy

So I have an array of the shape (5,5) , for eg:

```
c = array([[5, 8, 9, 3, 8],
   [5, 8, 7, 9, 6],
   [1, 8, 2, 2, 1],
   [2, 5, 8, 2, 6],
   [7, 6, 9, 5, 6]])
```

and another of the shape (7,7) , for eg :

```
a = array([[3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 2, 5],
   [4, 8, 2, 6, 5, 2, 3],
   [2, 1, 5, 8, 2, 7, 6],
   [3, 6, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5],
   [6, 1, 4, 1, 3, 5, 8],
   [8, 4, 9, 5, 1, 2, 8],
   [3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 2, 1]])
```

I would like to multiply c by a such that I get an array, call it k, with shape (3,3) such that

```
k[x,y] = np.sum(c * a[x:x+5,y:y+5]);  0 <=  x,y <= 2
```

Is there a mathematical operation that does this in numpy ?

Comment: and you are iterating `x` and `y` over `[0,1,2]`?  `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` should work to make a (3,3,5,5) view of `a`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that, how does this thing work and why are you suggesting a (3,3,5,5) view when I want a (3,3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [203]: c = np.array([[5, 8, 9, 3, 8],
     ...:    [5, 8, 7, 9, 6],
     ...:    [1, 8, 2, 2, 1],
     ...:    [2, 5, 8, 2, 6],
     ...:    [7, 6, 9, 5, 6]])
     ...: a = np.array([[3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 2, 5],
     ...:    [4, 8, 2, 6, 5, 2, 3],
     ...:    [2, 1, 5, 8, 2, 7, 6],
     ...:    [3, 6, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5],
     ...:    [6, 1, 4, 1, 3, 5, 8],
     ...:    [8, 4, 9, 5, 1, 2, 8],
     ...:    [3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 2, 1]])
```

As suggested in my comment:

```
In [204]: np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view?

In [205]: A = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a,(5,5))
In [206]: A.shape
Out[206]: (3, 3, 5, 5)
In [207]: k=(A*c).sum(axis=(2,3))
In [208]: k.shape
Out[208]: (3, 3)
In [209]: k
Out[209]: 
array([[626, 624, 706],
       [636, 564, 686],
       [583, 650, 623]])
```

testing

```
In [210]: k = np.zeros((3,3),int)
In [211]: for x in [0,1,2]:
     ...:     for y in [0,1,2]:
     ...:         k[x,y] = np.sum(c * a[x:x+5,y:y+5])
     ...: 
In [212]: k
Out[212]: 
array([[626, 624, 706],
       [636, 564, 686],
       [583, 650, 623]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw, do you know which one is faster in general, the numpy method or the one you tested with ? And, by how much?